# How to get mouse double click event while selecting text in CRichEditCtrl(C++)?

Tags: windows, mfc

> When I select any word with double click its select one WHITESPACE also(if there). I just wanna to select the word on which I double clicked.

For Example:

> Suppose there is a sentence like "I am rich control" in RichEdit box and i want to select "am" only on double click without including white space. Right now I am getting max range is 3 because "am" has two character plus one white space but i want max range 2 that means word length only.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Post your code.

Comment: I used ON_NOTIFY( EN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TITLER_SETUPWINDOW_TEXT_RICHEDIT2, OnTextRichEditSelChange ) in OnTextRichEditSelChange function i casted like SELCHANGE* pSelChange = reinterpret_cast< SELCHANGE* >( _pNMHDR ); so that when i double clicke I get the min and max range of selected text I mean highlighted text range which in including SPACE.

Comment: That doesn't help at all.  Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: There is a message `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC /  EM_SETWORDBREAKPROCEX` which allows to customize word breaking by  an own implementation: 

`LONG CALLBACK EditWordBreakProcEx(LPTSTR pchText, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code);` You can correct the selection behavior that way but it is not a 1-min task.

Comment: @SKSingh please don't put clarifications in comments but instead [edit] your question.

Comment: I think that this is standard behaviour with many applications.

Comment: Solved it by self recently! I was sarted to solve this problem 3day ago now it's completed. Thanks to all who interested to solve or comment to my question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle you are absolutely right but sometime we need to change that behaviour according to our project.

Comment: Consider proposing an answer with the solution that you have found.

Comment: [Click here to see solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Un-_xOsMMRSrWiNcm28hSrP5h-3RgwwC/view)